# getting text from react native fetch call

Tags: react-native, response, fetch

I'm not able to parse the data from the fetch call

Below is the method

```
onLoginPress=()=>{
      console.log("username="+this.state.username);
      console.log("password="+this.state.password);
      this.sendLoginRequest(this.state.username,this.state.password)
      .then((response) => {
          console.log("RESPONSEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE");
          console.log(response.text())
          console.log( Promise.resolve(response));
          response.json();
      })
      .then((responseJson) => {

        console.log(responseJson);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error(error);
      });


    };
```

The response i get it is a promise and i'm not able to get the token out of it.

Below is the log for response.text()

{
 _45: 0,                                                                                          _81: 1,
_65: '"3h8112qe2qobox3675ghmq9dtcbjvddc"',
_54: null }

For console.log( Promise.resolve(response)) the output is

```
{ 
_45: 0,
_81: 1,
_65: { type: 'default',
  status: 200,
  ok: true,
  statusText: undefined,
headers: { map: { connection: [ 'Keep-Alive' ],
'content-length': [ '34' ],
'content-type': [ 'application/json; charset=utf-8' ],
'set-cookie': [ 'persistent_shopping_cart=deleted; expires=Thu, 01-Jan-1970 00:00:01 GMT; Max-Age=0; path=/' ],
'cache-control': [ 'no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate' ],
expires: [ 'Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT' ],
pragma: [ 'no-cache' ],
server: [ 'Apache/2.4.23 (Ubuntu)' ],
'keep-alive': [ 'timeout=5, max=100' ],
[ 'Tue, 20 Jun 2017 06:58:16 GMT' ] } },
 url:'http://integration/customer/token',
 _bodyInit: '"3h8112qe2qobox3675ghmq9dtcbjvddc"',
 _bodyText: '"3h8112qe2qobox3675ghmq9dtcbjvddc"',
 bodyUsed: true 
},
_54: null }
```

responseJson returns undefined.

How to get the token(**3h8112qe2qobox3675ghmq9dtcbjvddc**) out of the data.

Thanks!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It appears that your API is returning text. So you need to call the `text()` method and return it to chain with a `then`:

```
onLoginPress=()=>{
      this.sendLoginRequest(this.state.username,this.state.password)
      .then((response) => {
         return response.text();
      })
      .then((responseJson) => {
         console.log(responseJson);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
         console.error(error);
      });
    };
```

If your API returns JSON, you would do exactly the same by swapping the `text()` call by a `json()` call. See the React Native [fetch doc](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/network.html).